# How can I play ".msv" audio file?

Tags: music-player

`.msv` is a Sony audio file type.

How can I play this file on 12.04?

Comment: Do you mind providing an online sample in order to download it and run some testing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, due to *.msv being proprietary in nature, it is extremely unlikely you'll find a way to actually play this file (unless Sony releases information on how to decode that file, which in itself is pretty unlikely).

Your best bet is to find a Windows machine that can convert the .msv into a .mp3, .wav, or *.ogg file and then playback the file in Ubuntu.

Comment: The journey cited above is no longer documented; that link is 404'd, dead, deceased, pining for the fjords.

Comment: @K7AAY thanks, I've updated the submission to remove the dead link. It seems like the only way is to get hold of a Windows machine (physical or virtual) and use that to convert the .msv file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try mplayer? I've read somewhere that it can play back these files.

```
sudo apt-get install mplayer
```

**Important note**: I did not try it. Please try to use it to play the msv files and report the result for others to use!

Comment: It doesn't work, with mplayer 1.3.0-7.